# Firebase Realtime Listener Concept - how to detach / unsubscribe from the listener?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[Get realtime updates with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) shows how to subscribe to, or listen to, document changes.

```
db.collection("cities").doc("SF")
    .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
        console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
    });
```

The example above makes sense. My question concerns detaching the listener. Is it accurate to say that when we want to detach / unsubscribe / unlisten to a document, we simply subscribe a second time to the same database reference?

...that's what it looks like, but I'm not crystal clear as to how/why?

```
var unsubscribe = db.collection("cities")
    .onSnapshot(function (){
      // Respond to data
      // ...
    });

// Later ...

// Stop listening to changes
unsubscribe();
```

This seems unnecessarily confusing. ...Why not simply have 2 methods, `.onSnapshot` and `.offSnapshot`? I supposed the only difference I see between the two provided examples is that the latter is assigned to a variable and that the method is called on the whole collection, rather than a single document.

So, is the bottom line: to unsubscribe, attach the `.onSnapshot` method to the parent collection and assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question concerns detaching the listener. Is it accurate to say that when we want to detach / unsubscribe / unlisten to a document, we simply subscribe a second time to the same database reference?

You don't need to subscribe twice.

The initial subscription you made returns a function which when called, unsubscribes you. You don't add that code a second time, instead store the return value from the initial call to the collection into a variable and invoke it when you intend to unsubscribe.

Imagine something like this:

```
function subscribe() {
  ... do things that subscribe me
  return function() {
    ... do things that unsubscribe me
  }
}

let unsubscribe = subscribe()

// later when I want to unsubscribe
unsubscribe()
```

Comment: i think you're correct. ...This Firebase/Firestore method is unnecessarily confusing / unintuitive to me though, i.e., seems like `.on` and `.off` would be much more understandable.

Comment: If you've used intervals before its something similar. In intervals you get an interval id as the return value and in order to clear the interval you need to use that ID that was returned. You can have many intervals on a single page, just as you can have many firebase subscriptions. Each unsubscribe function is unique and thus on and off isn't sufficient to describe the specific object that you want to unsubscribe without expensive computing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener), you just need to call that `unsubscribe` function to unsubscribe. The variable your listener returns is in fact a listener registration (see below for detail), so calling it to unregister kind of make sense.

It is indeed quite confusing, but since I have a similar set up on Android, and the way you unsubscribe in Android is call remove() on a `ListenerRegistration` instance (the same unsubscribe variable in web), I'd say it's only a design problem for the web.